# WSO2 Carbon log4j custom appender

Tags: log4j, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I wrote custom log4j appender to send logs from WSO2 AM 1.10.0 to RabbitMQ. there is an exception if I add the custom appender to WSO2 AM server.

[image: log appender error]

The steps of using appender:

1. Making a stand maven jar package which including all dependencies and put the jar file to lib folder,
   [image: lib folder]
2. Modifying log4j.properties under \repository\conf,

[image: log4j properties]

I am pretty sure the appender itself is working well as it has been used in a few apps to send off the logs to the queue.

[image: appender code]

[image: pom file]

Could anyone please advise me how to implement the custom log4j appender for WSO2 properly?

Thanks in advance,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a class loading issue. I think that happens because both WSO2 server and your custom jar contain log4j classes. Set scope `provided` like below for slf4j dependency, and see if it works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```